# Rest Assured cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I have created a java project and am getting the error in my console

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> RestAssured cannot be resolved to a variable

**added jar- rest-assured-4.3.3-dist.zip- all extracted**
from official website- https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Downloads

```
    here is my code-
   
//java class basics
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
    
    
    public class Basics {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  
//adding given, when , then conditions
  
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://rahulshettyacademy.com";  //added the base URI here 

//adding given condition here with log report
        given().log().all().queryParam("key", "qaclick123").header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body("{\r\n" +
        " \"location\": {\r\n" +
        " \"lat\": -38.383494,\r\n" +
        " \"lng\": 33.427362\r\n" +
        " },\r\n" +
        " \"accuracy\": 50,\r\n" +
        " \"name\": \" Muzammil house\",\r\n" +
        " \"phone_number\": \"(+91) 983 893 3937\",\r\n" +
        " \"address\": \"29, side layout, cohen 09\",\r\n" +
        " \"types\": [\r\n" +
        " \"shoe park\",\r\n" +
        " \"shop\"\r\n" +
        " ],\r\n" +
        " \"website\": \"http://google.com\",\r\n" +
        " \"language\": \"French-IN\"\r\n" +`enter code here`
        "}")                                            // end of body 
        .when().post("maps/api/place/add/json")       // added the resource here
        .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200); // validating response here
        
        }
        
        }
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: my email id; muzifire@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using maven. If that is the case you need to remove

```
<scope> test </scope>
```

node form your rest assured dependency in pom.xml file. If you are not using maven, then try to set build path and make sure that you added all your .jar files into the project.